# Why does np.array[None] update all values in that numpy arrray?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I found a bug in my code and while fixing that bug, and I noticed a peculiar behavior in numpy.

```
a = np.arange(10) # ints 0 -> 9
a[None] = 20

print(a) # output --> [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, ... 20]
```

Why do the values in every position get replaced with 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, not a bug. `a[None]` is not slicing/indexing but [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:%7E:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how%20numpy%20treats%20arrays,that%20looping%20occurs%20in%20C%20instead%20of%20Python.). What it does does is to provide a different view of the underlying data of `a`.

And since you are modifying this view with `a[None]=20`, you also modify `a`'s data, and therefore `a` itself.

Comment: `a[None]` is the same as `a[None,:]` and produces a (1,10) shaped view.  As you say it's that view that's being changed.